# SQL combine queries

Tags: sql

I want to do multiple queries in SQL at once, I know how to do each query separately but I can't find a way to combine all of them in a single query 
for this I use two different tables the first on is called booking

[image: Table booking]

For my first query I want to select  only the rows of the Rownumber of which PerfDate=2015-12-10 and PerfTime=16:00:00

My second table is quite huge its called seat and it looks like this

[image]

For my second query I want to get all the rows from the seat table which have different RowNumber when combaring with the outcome of the first query

Then from the outcome of the two queries I want to take the rows only of which the zone is front stalls

Can anyone please help me, thanks in advance

Comment: Hmmm... but what about your queries? You have shown onlyl tables structure/data, but there are no any queries in your question. Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the 1st query as a criteria for the first as below. So you would say select everything from the seats table where RowNumber is not in your first query. You could also filter the result of this, so that you only get 'Front Stalls' as below:

```
Select * from YourSeatTable
where RowNumber not in (Select RowNumber from YourTable1
                        where PerfDate = '2015-12-10' and PerfTime='16:00:00')
  and Zone = 'front stalls'
```

Comment: Thanks man really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this:

```
select * 
from seats s
where not exists (
  select 1
  from booking
  where 
        perfdate = '2015-12-10'
    and perftime = '16:00:00'
    and rownumber = s.rownumber
)
and zone = 'front stalls'
```

This query might run faster than using `where in`.